# How do I use GraphQL subscriptions?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am trying to hit a graphQL endpoint with my app which works when I when I send a query but returns null if I try to use the subscription method.  I am pretty sure the subscription endpoint is working because they have an API setup to test calls and I am able to get the request to work there.

I have tried hitting the endpoint directly with a request, using URQL and Apollo but I get the same result of a successful call but the value which is return is null(the key which is returned is correct).

```
import { Subscription } from "react-apollo";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";

const subscribe = gql`
  subscription {
    newMeasurement {
      value
    }
  }
`;

const query = gql`
  query {
    getMetrics
  }
`;

const HomePage = props => {

  return (
    <Subscription subscription={subscribe}>
    {({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
      return <div className="home">Hello, here is the newest number - 
</div>
    }}
    </Subscription>
  )
}
```

I know using a regular query in a Subscribe component isn't ideal, but I still get back the information I request so I have some confidence that the call is correct.  Is there something that I am missing when using subscribe?

Comment: The data inside the Subscription component will not be defined until a push actually occurs server-side. Subscriptions subscriptions are just listeners, they don't request any data when first connected.

Comment: Gotcha, I still don't understand why I am not getting sent any data when the API makes it seem like data is being sent out.  Even if I add something like ***{!data ? "loading" : data.newMeasurement}*** into the div within my return statement, it doesn't update.  Well, I can see it quickly update from "loading" but that quickly disappears once the call has a null value so it no longer returns anything.

Comment: If you mean you're seeing a request being made then that's the subscription call initiating the subscription. That request won't return any data, it's just letting the server know that a new listener has subscribed. If you want to fetch data from the server without waiting for a push, use a query and a Query component instead.

Comment: I guess I assumed that the subscription would send data if a push was sent from the server.  If the <Subscription> component is only initializing a subscription, how do I use that connection to do something useful?  The server should be setup to push new information out every few seconds.